# How to not generate a stack overflow when a sub procedure calls itself?

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers, stack-overflow

This code generates a stack overflow. I'm aware it is caused by the procedure calling itself. 
What can I do to avoid the stack overflow? Recalling the sub procedure and generating a new random number is the easiest thing to do, however it generates the overflow. The randomly generated number picks a random inventory item, then the if statement matches that number (random inventory item) with the quantity of that item from the deck inventory to make sure it isn't less than 1. If the inventory of that item is 0, the else plays and restarts the procedure, generating a new random number and doing the process all over again. In another procedure I have a function that if the deck's inventory becomes completely empty, then the discard pile replenishes the deck, making the discard pile empty, so there should never be a case where all randomly generated numbers can be associated item with a inventory of 0.

I wonder if I could somehow force the random number generator

```
Number = (DeckGroup(Rnd.Next(0, DeckGroup.Count)).ID)
```

not to generate numbers to inventory items `DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger` that are zero. By doing so I wouldn't even need to recall the function.
The random number is generated by a different branch in the same structure group.

```
Private Sub PlayElse()
        Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}
        'Reset Number Generator
            Number = (DeckGroup(Rnd.Next(0, DeckGroup.Count)).ID)
            Dim PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger As Integer
            For PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger = ChecksDynamicA To ChecksDynamicB
                If CardCheckBoxArray(TextBoxInteger).Checked = True And DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
                    DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
                    'Select the Player depending value of T
                    Select Case T
                        Case 0
                            Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
                        Case 1
                            Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger2 += 1
                        Case 2
                            Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger3 += 1
                        Case 3
                            Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger4 += 1
                        Case 4
                            Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger5 += 1
                    End Select
                    CardTypeArray(PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger) = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
                    CardCheckBoxArray(TextBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                    NumberArray(PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger) = Number
            Else
                If CardCheckBoxArray(TextBoxInteger).Checked = True And DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger < 0 Then
                    Call PlayElse()
                End If
                End If
        Next PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger
    End Sub
```

Comment: try changing `Number = (DeckGroup(Rnd.Next(0, DeckGroup.Count)).ID)` to `Number = (DeckGroup(Rnd.Next(1, DeckGroup.Count)).ID)` that will cause 1 to be the lowest random number availble to be returned.

Comment: I need to generate a 0 for index 0 though.

Comment: oh I see I misread. so you need to weed out all the id's of the DeckGroup objects with a QuantityInteger of 0?

Comment: exactly, by doing so no card with a quantity integer of 0 will be chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ to weed out all the objects you never want to get first and then use the collection returned by the linq instead of your original collection.

Something like:

```
Private Sub PlayElse()
    Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}
    'Reset Number Generator
    Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In DeckGroup Where r.QuantityInteger > 0 Select r
    If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Any Then
        Number = (temp(Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)

        ' ** Edit **: This will ensure that you only got 1 object back from the LINQ which can tell you whether or not you have bad data. You *can* exclude this check but its good practice to include it.

        Dim obj As LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group = Nothing

        Dim t = From r In temp Where r.ID = Number Select r
        If t IsNot Nothing AndAlso t.Count = 1 Then
            obj = t(0)
        End If

        If obj IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger As Integer
            For PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger = ChecksDynamicA To ChecksDynamicB
               ' ** Edit **
               obj.QuantityInteger -= 1
               'Select the Player depending value of T
                Select Case T
                    Case 0
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
                    Case 1
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger2 += 1
                    Case 2
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger3 += 1
                    Case 3
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger4 += 1
                    Case 4
                        Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger5 += 1
                End Select
                CardTypeArray(PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger) = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
                CardCheckBoxArray(TextBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                NumberArray(PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger) = Number
            Next PlayerQuantitySubtractionInteger
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `temp(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1` 
error message: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

Comment: @Gakko no Ato: edited the code. Before my code was trying to use the objects ID as the index. I added a second Linq statement in there to get the actual object you will want to work with. This may throw implicit conversion errors/warnings depending on how your environment is set up and the options you have on. you can get around this by explicitly `dim`ing `obj` as whatever class that is held in the DeckGroup collection.

Comment: 'QuantityInteger' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group)'.
I've even tried making the obj a new group (changing  `obj.QuantityInteger -= 1` to ` obj(0).QuantityInteger -= 1` in my structure group, however then I get the expression error again.

Comment: Try explicitly typing your collection and the `obj` object like what I did in the newest edits.(you may need to ctype `r` in the linq but your environment should tell you what type it is expecting.

Comment: Ok where would I Ctype it. I admit I'm a bit of an amature, so this project is my way I've trying to improve myself. Having it typed exactly how you had it gives me the error: `Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group)' cannot be converted to 'LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group'` . The underlined line was `Dim obj As LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group = From r In temp Where r.ID = Number Select r` on the right side of the operator.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to change the LINQ as well. The error is saying its returning a collection when its expecting a single object. So try `Dim obj As LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group = (From r In temp Where r.ID = Number Select r).FirstOrDefault`. I will make a few edits to the answer and show you another way of doing it that gives you more control over validating that you are actually getting what you expect back from the LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Pass through the list and determine only those that are valid.  Then randomly pull from that set.  Here is a simple version of it.  You could use LINQ as well, but this should be clear enough:

```
Dim validDeckGroupsIndexes As New List(Of Integer)

For ndx As Integer = 0 to DeckGroup.Count - 1
   If DeckGroup(ndx).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
      validDeckGroupsIndexes .Add(ndx)
   End If
Next ndx
```

Then use this:

```
Dim deckGroupNdx As Integer = Rnd.Next(0, validDeckGroupsIndexes.Count)

Number = DeckGroup(deckGroupNdx).ID
```

Comment: Works, however I get an index out of range error. The numbers are 0 to 13, yet it got 14 for the max. My guess is that it counted how many indexes there were overall. Would `Number = DeckGroup(deckGroupNdx - 1).ID` work perhalps?